# kubernetes create deployment using docker local image - image pull failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I tried to deploy kubernetes using minikube using both from local docker image and from docker hub. But both doesn't work.

method-1: 
Using save and load the tar file, created the image and it is available to kubectl.

```
root@arun-desktop-e470:/var/local/dprojects/elasticsearch# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |sort |uniq -c|grep elk
      2 elk/elasticsearch:latest
```

Execute below commands to create the deployment:

```
kubectl run elastic --image=elk/elasticsearch:latest --port=9200
kubectl expose deployment elastic --target-port=9200 --type=NodePort
minikube service elastic --url
```

From kubectl describe pod command,

```
  Warning  Failed     122m (x4 over 124m)   kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "elk/elasticsearch:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for elk/elasticsearch, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Method-2:
I did pushed the image to my docker hub repository, (https://hub.docker.com/r/get2arun/elk/tags) and then login to docker hub in the terminal and created the deployment again.

pushed to docker hub like below and hence I have permission to push and pull the images to my docker hub account. I have checked the "collaborators" under manage repositories and it has my docker hub id.

```
root@arun-desktop-e470:~# docker push get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1
The push refers to repository [docker.io/get2arun/elk]
19b7091eba36: Layer already exists 
237c06a69e1c: Layer already exists 
c84fa0f11212: Layer already exists 
6ca6c301e2ab: Layer already exists 
76dd25653d9b: Layer already exists 
602956e7a499: Layer already exists 
bde76be259f3: Layer already exists 
2333287a7524: Layer already exists 
d108ac3bd6ab: Layer already exists 
elasticsearch_v1: digest: sha256:6f0b981b5dedfbe3f8e0291dc17fc09d32739ec3e0dab6195190ab0cc3071821 size: 2214
```

kubectl run elasticsearch-v2 --image=get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1 --port=9200

From kubectl describe pods command:

```
  Normal   BackOff    21s               kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1"
  Warning  Failed     21s               kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    7s (x2 over 24s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1"
  Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for get2arun/elk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I removed the proxy settings and tried from open wifi account but still seeing permission denied.

This error message is not sufficient to identify the issue and hoping there should be some way to narrow down these kind of issues.

1. What happens in the background when Kubernetes is asked to use the
   local docker image or pull the image from docker hub?
2. How to get all the log information when deployment is started ?
3. What are the other sources for logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In method-1, as the image is not pushed to the repository, you have to use the imagePullPolicy.

#### Never try to pull the image

```
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

#### Try to pull the image, if it is not present

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I think IfNotPresent is ideal, if you want to use local image / repository. Use as per your requirement.

#### kubectl

```
kubectl run elastic --image=elk/elasticsearch:latest --port=9200 --image-pull-policy IfNotPresent
```

Comment: In method-2, pushed get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1 and in the method-2 logs it is correctly taking the image name, Pulling image "get2arun/elk:elasticsearch_v1". It could be issue in the kubernetes environment, i believe.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Setting imagePullPolicy for first approach, Is it possible to set this variable in the command line? Any idea why the second approach fails since the image is already available in my docker hub. how to set this variable for images created from dockerfile? Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Updated kubectl with --image-pull-policy option. You can debug by pulling the image manually in the Method-2. try `docker pull image:tag`